# Boundedness of $xg(x)$ and decay rate at infinity

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $|g(x)|<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $\left\|g\right\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}<\infty$. Moreover, we know that $|g(x)|\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and pretty much have control over ``how fast'' $g$ decays at infinity. The following seems somehow obvious, but want to make sure I am not overseeing any technicalities. If $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and

$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|xg(x)|=0,$$

is it true that

$$\left\|xg\right\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}<\infty$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty} |xg(x)|=0$, then by definition we have some $n$ such that $|x|>n\implies |xg(x)|<1$. Furthermore, for $|x|\le n$ we have $|xg(x)|=|x||g(x)|\le n\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)}$. Thus for any $x$ we have
$$|xg(x)|<\max(1,n\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)})$$
so $\|xg\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)}\le \max(1,n\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)})$.

Comment: Appreciate it. I needed to verify that the condition $$g(x)=o(1/|x|)$$ as $|x|\to\infty$ was what was needed to make the claim. Thanks again.

Comment: @user138589 Technically you can get away with $g(x)=O(1/|x|)$.

Comment: Actually, integration by parts on integrals of type                                  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}{xg_x(t,x)dx}$$                                                             was performed, where boundary terms, i.e $xg(t,x)$ at $\pm\infty$, were assumed to vanish. So the little guy is already there. Thanks again. Unfortunately I am not registered (may be I will do that), or else I'll vote you up.